# Is there a way to enable media print css to a normal view?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I developed a website with a bunch of print media queries to align stuff when printing the page. when you go to the print mode on web browser, the queries works great. but i want apply/remove those `@media print` queries on a regular web page without having to go into the printing mode.(by clicking a button) is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: like a print preview?

Comment: Just remove the print media in the link attribute?

Comment: @epascarello what do you mean?

Comment: @DanielA.White yes. but different from browsers print preview module.

Comment: Make it a normal stylesheet to test and add it back when done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to Boldewyn's answer, if you have `@media print` styles inside `<style>` tags, you can replace them with `@media screen`:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('style'), function(style) {
    style.innerText = style.innerText.replace(/@media print/gi, '@media screen');
});
```

See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g8pu05ct/).

Answer (score 4):

To add to yezzz's answer: If you have the print CSS linked in the HTML like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="...">
```

you can remove the `media` attribute to enable those styles everywhere, either on the server or with Javascript:

```
document.querySelector('[media="print"]').removeAttribute('media');
```

Note, that this doesn't work, if the statements in the print stylesheet are wrapped in a `@media print {}` rule.

Comment: I don't have a sperate style sheet to do that. instead i declared @media print {}. what i want to do is replicate what i get in the print view.

Comment: then use my answer

Answer (score 2):

First thing that comes to mind is use classes. Simple example to give you the general idea. If you had a button that toggles `emulateprint` class on the body you could use eg. this css:

```
body {
  color: black;
}
body.emulateprint {
  /* put same styles as @media print in here */
  color: red;
}

@media print {
  body {
    color:red;
  }
}
```