# Is there a way to toggle print media in browser from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I need a preview button that will show how the page will/might look when it's printed.

Hacked a working solution together with the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="layout.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">

const ps = document.querySelector('link[media=print]');
function togglePrintPreview(e)
{
    ps.media = ps.media == 'print' ? 'all' : 'print';
}
```

However, this of course only works if all print styles are in a separate stylesheet and as long as there are *no* `@media print` queries anywhere.

So... instead of that... is there a way to toggle the print media in the browser from Javascript? I.e. make the browser show the page as if the current media is `print`, rather than the default `screen`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37080744/is-there-a-way-to-enable-media-print-css-to-a-normal-view

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Um... sorry, but, duplicating *all* the print media styles under a class... 1) doesn't answer the question, and 2) is a messy solution... 

Comment: @JamesDonnelly And the other answer is to do exactly what I want to avoid, i.e. have two separate stylesheets and mess with the `<link media` attribute.